# Convert a string to a pre-existing variable?

Tags: python, string, variables

Is it possible to make a program that converts a string to a varname.
For example i have this

```
hey1 = 'one'
hey2 = 'two'
hey3 = 'three'

for c in range(3):
    string = "hey" + c
    print(string)
```

How do i convert string to a pre-existing variable?
Thanks

Comment: `string =  globals["hey" + c]`. But better not to do something like this. Use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way to do this is to capture all these variables in a `dict`. Using the `global` namespace to dynamically create variables is not considered good practice.

```
vars_ = dict()
for c in range(3):
    vars_[f"hey{c}"] = "some value"
```